# How to use php to find word between word

Tags: php, regex, string

Hello I have html file I want to find word in matching position Like

> Hello my name is jim. Hello my name is emma. hello my name is test.

What i want to do is echo word after `my name is` and before `.` (DOT) I have this php function But it will just echo first name jim how i can loop

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("test.html");

$name = cut_str($data,'my name is ','.');
echo $name;


function cut_str($str, $left, $right){
    $str = substr(stristr($str, $left), strlen($left));
    $leftLen = strlen(stristr($str, $right));
    $leftLen = $leftLen ? -($leftLen) : strlen($str);
    $str = substr($str, 0, $leftLen);
    return $str;
}

?>
```

Comment: You must be looking for [something like this](https://ideone.com/Ig205n), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` as

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=(my name is))(.*?)(?=(\.))/i', 'Hello my name is jim. Hello my name is emma. hello my name is test.',$res);
print_r($res[0]);
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=(my name is))` Positive Lookbehind - Capturing group `(my name is)`
  `my name is` matches the characters `my name is` literally
- `.*?` matches any character (except newline)
- `(?=(\.))` Positive Lookahead - `\.` matches the character `.` literally
- `i modifier:` insensitive. Case insensitive match `(ignores case of [a-zA-Z])`

Or you can also use it as

```
preg_match_all('/my\sname\sis(.*?)\./i', 'Hello my name is jim. Hello my name is emma. hello my name is test.',$res);
print_r($res[1]);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/418226)

Comment: THANKS guys for such fast answer i got my code working with Narendra Sisodia codes thanks great site for newbie like  me

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$name = preg_match_all('~My name is (.+?)\.~', $data, $names);
print_r($names[1]);
```

The `.` is any character.

The `+` is one or more characters.

The `?` stops the matching at the first `.`.

The `~` are delimiters telling the regex where to stop and start.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/418218

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dO8mQ4/1

Depending on how loose or strict you want it you may need modifiers.

You could do

```
$name = preg_match_all('~My\s+name\s+is\s+(.+?)\.~i', $data, $names);
print_r($names[1]);
```

This allows one or more whitespace (tab, newline, space) (\s+) between each word and makes the words case insensitive(`i` after delimiter).

Comment: Your demo finds only one name. *Edit: No, in fact, it's just that it's case sensitive, sorry. :)

Comment: Yea, just add updated noting that and improvements that could be added, not sure how strict OP wants it.